# Password based encryption-last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: java, password-encryption

I have a problem with password based encryption/decryption using PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC algorithm. When I get to cipher.doFinal i get: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption.

```
public static String encrypt(String salt, String password, byte[] object) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt.getBytes(), 1000);
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());

        SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

        Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
        encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

        byte[] encryptedObject = encryptionCipher.doFinal(object);

    return new String(encryptedObject);
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedObject, String password, String salt) throws GeneralSecurityException{
    PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt.getBytes(), 1000);
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());

        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory
                = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
        SecretKey passwordKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, passwordKey, parameterSpec);

        byte[] decryptedObject = cipher.doFinal(encryptedObject.getBytes());

    return new String(decryptedObject);
}
```

And main:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
String text = "plaintext";
String salt = "salt";
String password = "password";
String encrypted = encrypt(salt, password, text.getBytes());
String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password, salt);
System.out.println(decrypted);
```

Have I missed something? When others got this exception they didn't use the same salt for encryption and decryption or they didn't decode encrypted text from Base64. None of these helped with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output of encrypt and decrypt should be byte[] not String.

Answer (score 0):

The `PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC` should be used for key generation process only, not for encryption/decryption process itself.

You should continue only with (for example):

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
```